# Use SVG plots when Publish-ing to HTML

Tags: matlab, svg, publish

This question was posted on Matlab Central (http://goo.gl/MkU8P) but hasn't gotten any answer. I thought someone here might have a lead.

I use `publish()` quite a bit to produce online class notes. It's working well but frankly, I find the PNG plots to be of awful quality. I've tried setting `figureSnapMethod='antialiased'` and that's a bit better but I mostly find the result fuzzy.

What would be awesome is to produce SVG plots. Is there any way to do that? I suppose it would have to involve `plot2svg` somehow (also from File Exchange) since SVG output seems to be only supported for Simulink models. Or perhaps someone has a better solution using some other high quality format.

Answer (score 1):

before using publish you should set some options to change imageForamt. by default it is set to PNG format which is not good for reports, papers, etc. what you need is a vector graphic image, something like an eps or emf file formats. (in such case it does not matter how much you zoom in , it never becomes fuzzy or low resolution).

Any image format that your installed version of Microsoft Office can import, including 'png' , 'jpg', 'bmp',and 'tiff'. If the 'figureSnapMethod' is 'print',then you can also specify 'eps', 'epsc', 'eps2', 'ill', 'meta',and 'pdf'

for HTML output any format publishes successfully
for latex output any format publishes successfully

I suggest you to use eps, it is the best. and remember SVG is not supported in publish. ;)

you should add this part to your command:

```
 'imageFormat','eps'
```

Comment: My goal is to publish to html, so eps or pdf aren't an option. Yet I would like to use a vector format to produce high-quality plots. At this point I'm wondering whether anyone knows how to hack `publish` to use SVG.

Comment: Not what the poster was looking for, but still a useful answer. +1, thanks!